# Vue, Vuex, and Vue-Cli for publishing library of Single File Components with Vuex Module

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm new to Vue, Vuex and the Vue-Cli.

I have an application structure like:

```
src/
  - components/
  -+++- grouped/
      -+++- a.vue
      -+++- b.vue
  -+++- c.vue

  - store/
  -+++- modules/
      -+++- mymodule/
          -+++- actions.js
          -+++- mutations.js
          -+++- state.js
          -+++- getters.js
```

all components assume that `mymodule` is registered.

Components `a`, `b`, and `c` can function independently or together.

How can I publish these components and their vuex module together on npm?

I've figured out a partial solution. See:

- https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/vue-vuex-sfc-lib
- https://codesandbox.io/s/qvz4jy9429

Comment: I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/justfrontendthings/how-to-create-and-publish-your-own-vuejs-component-library-on-npm-using-vue-cli-28e60943eed3) to publish my component library to npm. You can also go through the comments. This isn't an answer but hopefully can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @JeremyWalters seen it but not relevant as it doesn't handle the store aspect...

Comment: @JeremyWalters I also tried the guide for some of the components that did not have the vuex store and when I try to import the package I get "ModuleNotFoundError"

Comment: That guide register the components globally on vue state. So you can just call the component in the template

Comment: @JeremyWalters except when I npm install the library I can't call the component because I can not import the library

Comment: You will need create an example project on github for me to see why. This is my working component [Lib](https://github.com/payfind/shop2shop-vue-components)

Comment: @JeremyWalters see update

Comment: @SumNeuron I am facing the same issue. I want to a vuex in my library. did you find any solution?